# How to copy the value of one sheet to another sheet Google sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a customer sheet and a invoice sheet

When I go to the invoice sheet D12 and I type the invoice ID that's located in the customer sheet, then I get all the data from some vlookups.

But what I want is this:

I click on a cell in the customer sheet where the invoice number is located in that row. I activate the test1 function and the invoice number should be changed in the invoice sheet D12.

But when I run this script I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function setActiveSheet in object Sheet

Does anyone know how to change the invoice D12 cell?

```
function test1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var rowSource = ss.getRange(row, 8);
  ss.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Invoice'), true);
  ss.getRange('D12').activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setValue(rowSource);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code examples on https://developers.google.com/apps-script and other places use `ss` to hold a Class Spreadsheet object rather than a Class Sheet object.

Try replacing

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

by

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```